# Rate users for their general behavior / attitude

Tags: feature-request, users, feedback

There are a lot of very active and intelligent users on Stackoverflow that are really adding a lot of value to this platform and they deserve their reputation points in my opinion. But a few users are just answering all questions they can find with a imprecise or even incorrect answer. Or just asking something like 20 questions a day (19 you could just google and maybe one interesting/real question). And they do it over and over again.

Do you think it would be a good idea if users could rate the general behavior a other user in his profile? (Maybe just high reputation members could do it) Or just give a feedback to the user of his general behavior?

Anyone can sometimes give a false answer from time to time or just ask a not very good formulated question but if they do it over and over, its getting annoying.

Comment: What's the matter? Downvotes too *cool* for you?

Comment: Jeff has said again and again that you should be rating the post not the user.

Comment: Downvotes are not too cool for me :P

Comment: Also, "19 you could just google". Sure, and for which you would get answers lost on I-don't-know-which-forum-asking-me-to-register-to-actually-read-it. If you can get a full answer to your particular question, by a human being, it is always better. And also, it will feed "google" with more clever answers, easier to get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Chris noted, you should be rating the *information* not the *user*.

If there are behavior problems, this is what flagging for moderator attention is for.

Comment: ok. Does a user keep points he has earned on a answer or question he has deleted?

Comment: @meo: I don't believe so - but the change in rep may not occur immediately. There would be a change, typically, upon a recalc of reputation.

Comment: ok this answers my dilemma.

Answer (score 4):

Users are rated on their general behaviour: Reputation.

Answering a lot of questions is not a bad thing - if the information inside is correct, it will be upvoted. If it solves the question, it will be answered. If neither are true, the person gains nothing. Thus, high-rep users sort of have to have done well!