# examples of abusive posts

Tags: discussion, abuse

I see some posts here talking about abusive users and posts on SO, yet I've seldom, if ever encountered one in my questions and answers.

Can the community point to some examples of users and posts considered abusive?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22177#22177

Comment: Hardly. If something is really abusive, it's usually deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is something I've gone back and forth on with the otherwise-insightful Shog9.)

Paradoxically it's hard to point to abusive posts and comments in our community *precisely because it gets removed*, and **that's the way it should be!**

We aren't going to leave poison and abuse laying around in the community. It's the equivalent of failing to clean up broken glass in a park.

Comment: Agreed. If the system is working, theoretically there won't be any 'problem posts.'

Comment: Yup, you guys are doing a great job.

Answer (score 3):

**The focus should be on the posts, not the users.**  As [has been discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49546/rate-users-for-their-general-behavior-attitude/49549#49549) ad nauseum, it's behavior that should be deemed problematic, not individuals.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea.

Meta discussions of abuse usually include direct links, but those are for the isolated incidents. In general providing examples right now will simply be pointing fingers at the users who are linked to. It will imply that the *user* is a perfect example of offensive behaviour and not the *action*.

Furthermore, when examples of abuse come up, the correct response is to deal with them fairly and swiftly. Usually the offending remark or incident is removed from the site, because it simply doesn't belong. Keeping those examples around would contribute to a 'broken windows' situation, where our 'examples of bad behaviour' would be considered by the uninitiated as examples of acceptable behaviour.